# .NET CORE Background Service Stops Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5, background-service

In my application I have a Background Service whit overridden StartAsync method to connect to a VOIP server for listening to its events continuously.

This application is hosted on IIS 10 (Server1) and VOIP is on Centos7 (Server2).

The problem is StartAsync method not working until I browse website inside IIS, also it seems to be stopped about an hour later and I have to browse website again to make it start!

As a tip, this application is supposed to be a SignalR hub so clients can connect to it and get related events for further operations.

Is this a correct approach for listen to another server events as a background service? Or it could be implemented under better solution?

```
    public class PBXEventListener : BackgroundService
    {
        private static AriClient ActionClient = new AriClient(
                    new StasisEndpoint("10.3.3.1", 8088, "asterisk", "asterisk"),
                    "HelloWorld", true);
        private readonly IHubContext<AsteriskHub> _asterHub;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _service;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _deviceStates = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

        public PBXEventListener(IHubContext<AsteriskHub> asterHub, IServiceProvider service, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _asterHub = asterHub;
            _service = service;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var scope = _service.CreateScope())
                {
                    var callStatRepo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICallStatRepository>();
                    _deviceStates = callStatRepo.GetAndSetLastStates();
                }

                ActionClient.OnConnectionStateChanged += ActionClientOnConnectionStateChanged;
                ActionClient.OnDialEvent += ActionClientOnDialEvent;
                ActionClient.OnChannelStateChangeEvent += ActionClientChannelStateChangeEvent;
                ActionClient.OnDeviceStateChangedEvent += ActionClientDeviceStateChangeEvent;

                ActionClient.Connect();

            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that your IIS apppool is set to sleep after 1hour of inactivity?

Comment: if you want to run as a background service; *run as a background service*, i.e. a Windows service or linux daemon; an IIS application is for a web server

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in IIS. IIS processes will (and should) restart periodically. Like Mark says, use an actual background service.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks Marc, but it supposed to be SignalR hub so clients can connect to get events.

Comment: @Mehdi honestly, I don't see the relevance; you *can* configure IIS not to spin down, of course, or you could just host in Kestrel as a windows service rather than involving IIS (depending on what IIS features, if any, you are using)

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks again, I was reading an article about what you pointed to https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2019/10/15/windowsservice/